# Deobfuscate PHP script (php obfuscator 1.4)

Tags: php

situation very simple - Previous programmer was fired. And the best thing that he did - it obfuscated PHP code and deleted the source files. I try to decode the scripts by my self, but the code doesn't work after my changes. Maybe someone can help with the decoding?

> **[pastebin.com/pfQtzgGx](http://pastebin.com/pfQtzgGx)**
>
> **[pastebin.com/wPaQ9L6Y](http://pastebin.com/wPaQ9L6Y)**
>
> **pastebin.com/sgiEaCG0**
>
> **pastebin.com/xC0q55U2**
>
> **pastebin.com/pVXtk78k**

For decoding  i try this extention: evalhook

Comment: Lol. It's a free lesson to never store the sources in one place, but in a control version instead. PS: this question is not technical actually, but legal.

Comment: Hopefully the source code wasn't too large. If there's no backup and no version control, most likely the only thing to do is to 1) sue the guy who did that and 2) restart the project from scratch.

Comment: For the future - good advice. But now, as a new programmer i should now solve the problem - write again this code or try to decode it. So, i think that somebody meet with problem of decoding same files.

Comment: You might need a bounty for this one ;)

Comment: I'm doing the wPaQ9L6Y one, give me couple minutes...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Emm I wanted to do just one, but I got sort of hooked in this :) 
It should be readable.
Try it out, but I would be really surprised if there was no mistake. But it's easy to guess what it's for now and how to repair it.

Here's first one: (pfQtzgGx)

```
require_once('config.php');
if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    $get_lang = mysql_escape_string($_GET['lang']);
} else {
    $get_lang = 'ru';
}
$name1 = 'name1_'. $get_lang;
$name2 = 'name2_' . $get_lang;
$get_step = 0;
$code_len = 0;
if (isset($_GET['step'])) {
    $get_step = mysql_escape_string($_GET['step']);
}
if (isset($_GET['code_len'])) {
    $code_len = mysql_escape_string($_GET['code_len']);
}
if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
    $get_term = mysql_escape_string($_GET['term']);
}
if ($get_step == 3 or $get_step == 4) {
    $get_term_b64dec = base64_decode($get_term);
    $get_term_binary = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($get_term_b64dec) - 1; $i += 2) {
        $get_term_binary .= chr(hexdec($get_term_b64dec[$i] . $get_term_b64dec[$i + 1]));
    }
    $_9  = preg_split('/[.]/', $get_term_binary, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $_10 = $_9[4];
    if ($get_step == 3) {
        $get_step = 0;
    } else {
        $get_step = 1;
    }
} else {
    $_10 = substr($get_term, 0, strpos($get_term, '.'));
}
if ($get_step == 0) {
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT 
        pt_len.$name1 AS code, 
        pt_len.$name1 AS field 
        FROM feconi.pt_sort1 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN feconi.pt_len ON pt_sort1.id_pt_standard = pt_len.id_pt_standard 
        WHERE pt_sort1.id = \"$_10\"
            AND pt_sort1.size1 BETWEEN pt_len.s1_min 
            AND pt_len.s1_max 
            AND pt_sort1.id_pt_type = pt_len.id_pt_type";
} else {
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT 
        pt_len.ID AS code, 
        pt_len.$name2 AS field 
        FROM feconi.pt_sort1 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN feconi.pt_len ON pt_sort1.id_pt_standard = pt_len.id_pt_standard 
        WHERE pt_sort1.id = \"$_10\" 
            AND pt_len.$name1 = \"$code_len\"
            AND pt_sort1.size1 
                BETWEEN pt_len.s1_min AND pt_len.s1_max 
            AND pt_sort1.id_pt_type = pt_len.id_pt_type";
}
$result = @mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($result); $i++) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            $output = '[{"value":"' . $row['code'] . '","text":"' . $row['field'] . '"}';
        } else {
            if ($i == 0) {
                $output = '[{"value":"' . $row['code'] . '","text":"' . $row['field'] . '"}';
            } else {
                $output = $output . ',{"value":"' . $row['code'] . '","text":"' . $row['field'] . '"}';
            }
        }
    }
    $output = $output . ']';
    echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $output . ');';
}
```

Here's the second one: wPaQ9L6Y

```
<?
require_once('config.php');

if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
    $get_term = mysql_escape_string($_GET['term']);
}

if (isset($_GET['lvl'])) {
    $get_lvl= mysql_escape_string($_GET['lvl']);
} else {
    $get_lvl= 1;
}

if (isset($_GET['term1'])) {
    $get_term1 = mysql_escape_string($_GET['term1']);
}

if (isset($_GET['term2'])) {
    $get_term2 = mysql_escape_string($_GET['term2']);
} else {
    $get_term2 = 1;
}

if ($get_term2 == 2) {
    $term1_b64dec = base64_decode($get_term1);

    $term1_binary = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($term1_b64dec) - 1; $i += 2) {
        $term1_binary .= chr(hexdec($term1_b64dec[$i] . $term1_b64dec[$i + 1]));
    }

    $term1_ID = preg_split('/[.]/', $term1_binary, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $sort1_ID = $term1_ID[4];

    if ($get_term2 == 3) {
        $get_term2 = 0;
    } else {
        $get_term2 = 1;
    }
} else {
    $sort1_ID = substr($get_term1, 0, strpos($get_term1, '.'));
}

$query  = "SELECT 
    pt_len.code_len AS code_len, 
    pt_len.w_min AS w_min, 
    pt_len.w_max AS w_max, 
    pt_len.l_min AS l_min, 
    pt_len.l_max AS l_max, 
    pt_len.w_step AS w_step, 
    pt_len.l_step AS l_step, 
    pt_len.width AS width, 
    pt_len.len AS len, 
    pt_len.default_w AS default_w, 
    pt_len.default_l AS default_l, 
    pt_sort1.weight AS weight, 
    pt_sort1.measure2 AS measure2 
    FROM feconi.pt_len 
    INNER JOIN pt_sort1 ON pt_len.id_pt_standard = pt_sort1.id_pt_standard 
        AND pt_len.id_pt_type = pt_sort1.id_pt_type 
    WHERE pt_len.ID = \"$get_term\" 
        AND pt_len.level <= \"$get_lvl\" 
        AND pt_sort1.ID = \"$sort1_ID\"";
$result = @mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $output = '{"code_len":"' . $row['code_len'] . '","w_min":"' . $row['w_min'] . '","w_max":"' . $row['w_max'] . '",';
    $output = $output . '"l_min":"' . $row['l_min'] . '","l_max":"' . $row['l_max'] . '","w_step":"' . $row['w_step'] . '",';
    $output = $output . '"l_step":"' . $row['l_step'] . '","width":"' . $row['width'] . '","len":"' . $row['len'] . '",';
    $output = $output . '"default_w":"' . $row['default_w'] . '","default_l":"' . $row['default_l'] . '",';
    $output = $output . '"weight":"' . $row['weight'] . '","measure2":"' . $row['measure2'] . '"}';

    echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $output . ');';
}
?>
```

Third one: (sgiEaCG0)

```
require_once('config.php');

if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    $get_lang = mysql_escape_string($_GET['lang']);
} else {
    $get_lang = 'ru';
}

$name_lang = 'name_' . $get_lang;
$_2 = 0;
$_3 = 0;
if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
    $get_term = mysql_escape_string($_GET['term']);
}
$query = "SELECT 
    pt_unt.$name_lang AS `text`, 
    pt_unt.id AS value 
    FROM rol_lenunt 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN pt_unt ON rol_lenunt.unt = pt_unt.id 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN pt_len ON pt_len.code_len = rol_lenunt.len 
    WHERE pt_len.id = \"$get_term\"";
$result = @mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $output = '[';
    for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($result); $i++) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        if (strlen($output) <> 1) {
            $output .= ',';
        }
        $output .= '{"text":"' . $row['text'] . '","value":"' . $row['value'] . '"}';
    }
    $output .= ']';
    echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $output . ');';
} else {
    echo 'sorry';
}
```

#4: (xC0q55U2)

```
if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
    $get_q = mysql_escape_string($_GET['q']);
}
$get_q = base64_decode($get_q);
$q_binary = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($get_q) - 1; $i += 2) {
    $q_binary .= chr(hexdec($get_q[$i] . $get_q[$i + 1]));
}
$q_splitted = preg_split('/[.]/', $q_binary, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$_4 = $q_splitted[4];
$_5 = $q_splitted[6];
$_6 = $q_splitted[15];
$_7 = $q_splitted[16];
$_8 = '{"value":"' . $_4 . '.' . $_5 . '","APclass":"' . $_6 . '","apOther":"' . $_7 . '"}';
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $_8 . ');';
```

And finaly: pVXtk78k

```
require_once('config.php');
if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
    $get_q = mysql_escape_string($_GET['q']);
}
$query = "SELECT 
lc_region.adv_supplier AS adv_supplier , 
lc_region.adv_supplier_web AS adv_supplier_web , 
lc_region.adv_stock AS adv_stock , 
lc_region.adv_stock_web AS adv_stock_web , 
lc_region.adv_producer AS adv_producer , 
lc_region.adv_producer_web AS adv_producer_web 
FROM lc_region 
WHERE lc_region.id = $get_q";
$result = @mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($result); $i++) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $output = '{"trade_0_filed_2":"' . $row['adv_supplier'] . 
            '","trade_0_filed_2_web":"' . $row['adv_supplier_web'] . 
            '","trade_1_filed_2":"' . $row['adv_stock'] . 
            '","trade_1_filed_2_web":"' . $row['adv_stock_web'] . 
            '","trade_2_filed_2":"' . $row['adv_producer'] . 
            '","trade_2_filed_2_web":"' . $row['adv_producer_web'] . '"}';
    }
    echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $output . ');';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. We find old versions of this files end correct them with this codes. Now all works perfect. You save my life! =)

Comment: It's hard to believe it works, I had no way to test it. I'm happy to hear that.

Comment: Well done, I wouldn't have thought it could be decoded to such readable code.

Comment: Great job, any insights on how you did this? Thanks!

Comment: That $GLOBALS['_BLABLABLA_'] holds encoded names of functions, so cut it out, run it separately to see what it looks like when decoded, then search+replace all of them. The function _1432558226($i) (whatever the numbers are in each file) holds encoded strings, so I did the same thing, run it and see what's the output, then search+replace all of them. Then I looked what those variables are and gave them some reasonable names. Finaly just cleaned it a bit from things like "round(0 + 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2)", which always evaluates to one. That's all, no tricks really.